# VS SetupProject registry entry for custom file-extensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, registry, setup-project

Within my project I create backup-files with a **custom extension** ".tp"

The software will be distributed with a **Setup Project as an installer**.

Which steps do I have to follow in order to add a **registry entry via Setup project** to let the OS show my custom icon? Is that possible?

I found a few solutions on how to do it manually, but I would like to have the installer (Setup project) to do it for me...
Could not find anything on that...

info:
I use Visual Studio Express 2017
Software is written in C#

EDIT:
In the meantime I was able to add a registry entry into the right directory, but I am not sure how to point to the .ico file, and on how to call SHChangeNotify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio setup projects have a File Types on Target Machine editor, so there's no need for registry manipulation. If you add a new file type (your .tp) the IDE's property window on the .tp (hit F4) will show a window where you add your icon. The %Open properties window is where you add the program to open the extension. It's not overly complicated. This seems to cover it in extra detail:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58005-file-associations-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that out and if it was correct (what I strongly believe) I will mark your answer!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Project has been taking some time... 

Your information helped very much! Thank you!